# I need help for the Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python

```
name = ''
while name != 'your name':
    print('Please type your name.')
    name = input()
print('Thank you!')
```

When I input 'your name' or whatever, it doesn't work. I used the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python.

```
(Error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CSA\Desktop\superami.py", line 4, in <module>
    name = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'j' is not defined)
```

Comment: working fine here: https://repl.it/languages/python3 (copy and paste your code to test). You could however, use `name.lower()` to avoid having inequality in "joe" and "Joe"

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: You're probably using python2. Upgrade to python3 and it should work

Comment: As @TedKleinBergman said, to run python 3 in your terminal, type `python3` and not `python`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in python 2

```
name = ''
while name != 'your name':
    print('Please type your name.')
    name = raw_input()
print('Thank you!')
```

Comment: Didn't know i was using python 2, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Python 2, where [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) will evaluate the string provided by the user.

You should either:

- Use Python 3. Python 2 is EOL in 2020.
- Use `raw_input`

Comment: I'll use python 3. Thank you

Comment: We already reached [end-of-life for Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).